# How to retrieve image BLOB from formData of jquery ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am doing an ajax popup to upload image into filesystem. The image uploading process has the following steps..

1. choosing the file and crop it to needed size.
2. the result image is displayed in `<img>` tag src as Base64 Code.
3. converting the Base64 to Blob to send via ajax

Here is the code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_save').on('click', function () {
            var PaymentStatus = $("#PaymentStatus").val();
            var image = $('#image-id').val();

            var base64ImageContent = image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            var blob = base64ToBlob(base64ImageContent, 'image/png');
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('picture', blob);
            formData.append('PaymentStatus', PaymentStatus);
            $.ajax({
                    data: formData,
                    url:"/login/advshop/add",
                    method: 'GET',
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("form submitted");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                        alert('error');
                        //alert(result);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

but I am not able to get the data in my controller..

```
public function add() {
    print_r($_POST['picture']); 
}
```

and the **error message** is..

> Message: Undefined index: picture

Comment: I think you have to user **method: 'POST'** instead of **method: 'GET'** as in controller you are trying to get data from POST request

Comment: I am sorry that was just a typing error..i used the POST method

Comment: before your ajax call please put a `console.log(formData);` and let us know what it says

Comment: If you are emulating a file upload as a normal HTML form would send it, then you need to use $_FILES.

Comment: i need to pass the image through ajax. the image is in base64 format, when it pass as string the string breaks...not able to save the file using  file_put_contents(). saves a corrupted image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please see my answer..

```
       $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#btn_save').on('click', function () {
            var image = $('#image-id').val();
            var base64ImageContent = image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
            var PaymentStatus = $("#PaymentStatus").val();
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('image', base64ImageContent);
            formData.append('PaymentStatus', PaymentStatus);



            $.ajax({
                data: formData,
                url: "/login/advshop/add",
                method: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("form submitted");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('error');
                    //alert(result);

                }
            });
        });
    })
```

In Controller.

```
    public function add() {


        $data = base64_decode($_POST['image']);


       file_put_contents('images/test.jpg', $data);
     }
```

you can directly pass the Base64 image content via ajax using formData append.decode the base64 content and put it in file_put_contents() function.

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is that you wanna convert the uploaded image into base64 string and then you wanna pass this string to controller via ajax ..is it brother..

Comment: exactly...i choose this method because passing base64 long string through ajax is not applicable. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i too faced that problem..so first take a hiddenfield in your form and give id and value for hiddenfield as value of hidden field is the converted string .then you can easily get the value of hiddenfield i.e. base64 string into a variable in js by getElementById then pass the variable to controller..there youcan access through $_POST['id of hiddenfield']. then you can store the value into database directly by save().

Comment: You can re edit by clicking on edit button your first answer rather posting another one.

Comment: in this case..you are telling to convert the base64 code to string format and then pass to js..right?

Answer (score 0):

yes ,no need to convert base64 to string..base64 returns string so u use this string to value of hiddenfield.

Comment: can u share your code? the image string breaks i think.